# i want to display both single image and multiple image on a single page but getting error undefined offset 1

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

here is my view page...

```
<?php $images = json_decode($row->image);

  <?php if($images>1){?>
          <img class="primary-image" src="<?php echo base_url()?>images/<?php echo $images[0] ?>" alt="" />
          <img class="secondary-image" src="<?php echo base_url()?>images/<?php echo $images[1] ?>" alt="" />
    <?php}
    else
    {?>
          <img class="primary-image" src="<?php echo base_url()?>images/<?php echo $images[0] ?>" alt="" />

 <?php }?>
```

here iam getting an error like "undefined offset 1".here iam fetching both single image and multiple image under single image iam getting this error

Comment: use `sizeof($images) > 1` instead of `$images>1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php $images = json_decode($row->image); if(!empty($images)) {
echo '<img class="primary-image" src="'.base_url().'images/'.$images[0].'" alt="" />';
if(isset($images[1])) { 
    echo '<img class="secondary-image" src="'.base_url().'images/'.$images[1].'" alt="" />';
} } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use `if(count($images) > 1)` instead of `if($images > 1)`

```
<?php $images = json_decode($row->image);

  <?php if(count($images) > 1){?>
      <img class="primary-image" src="<?php echo base_url()?>images/<?php echo $images[0] ?>" alt="" />
      <img class="secondary-image" src="<?php echo base_url()?>images/<?php echo $images[1] ?>" alt="" />
<?php}
else
{?>
      <img class="primary-image" src="<?php echo base_url()?>images/<?php echo $images[0] ?>" alt="" />
```